# Can't get a class to get removed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know if it's me or there's really something strange here, but I can't remove the class active from all buttons (third line of the following code). All buttons keep the class active.

Any idea ? Am I to hungry to code ? Thanks for you help

```
            $(document).on('click', '#filters button', function (event) {

                jQuery('#unit-selector svg .active').removeClass('active');
                jQuery('#filters button .active').removeClass('active');

                jQuery(this).addClass('active');

                // Get Size Value
                var size = jQuery(this).attr('id');

                if (size == "floor-show-3") {
                    jQuery('#unit-selector svg .three').addClass('active');
                }

                if (size == "floor-show-4") {
                    jQuery('#unit-selector svg .four').addClass('active');
                }

                if (size == "floor-show-5") {
                    jQuery('#unit-selector svg .five').addClass('active');
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove `active` class from all buttons, you need to use:

```
$('#filters button.active').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

Or, you can also do the above *two-line* logic in *one-line* like

```
$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
```

Please note this *one-line* logic will only work if the buttons are next to each other like:

```
<button>Add</button>
<button>Edit</button>
<button>Cancel</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of `removeClass` seems okay, but I can't be sure that your selector is correctly selecting your buttons without seeing the button markup. Can you share that as well?